# What are micro instructions?

Tags: computer-science, cpu-architecture

Are micro instructions low level assembly language or are micro instructions binary digits such as 1 or 0 that the computer uses to process things at very low level? Whenever I try to search up for micro instructions, I am unable to find much info.

Comment: With the term "micro instructions", do you really mean [*microcode*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microcode)?

Comment: What context did you see this term used in?  Possibly talking about Intel or AMD micro-*ops*, aka uops or μops?  http://www.lighterra.com/papers/modernmicroprocessors/ for an overview of CPU architecture.  Also maybe https://www.realworldtech.com/sandy-bridge/.  https://agner.org/optimize/.  https://www.realworldtech.com/risc-vs-cisc/ for an intro to how PPro first started decoding x86 code to uops.  Or in the context of much older micro-coded CPUs like Z80, the CPU ran machine instructions with multiple internal microcode instructions that were known to some degree.

Comment: [What is a microcoded instruction?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40366643) for that modern meaning of microcode, and multi-uop vs. single uop x86 instructions.  Also [What exactly is microcode and how does it differ from firmware?](https://superuser.com/q/1283788) for stuff like 6502 microcode.  Or [How was microcode implemented in retro processors?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/6656)

Answer (score 0):

A single instruction in microcode.
The most basic instruction in the computer, like moving the contents of a register to the ALU.

We need several micro-instructions to run complex machine instruction